# Is there any alternative to statsmodels summary function in sklearn library in python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas

i am using the below code :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X=sm.add_constant(X_train)
model=sm.OLS(y_train,X).fit()
model.summary()
```

but I need alternative to this summary() in sklearn library to check the summary of the logistic model for a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still wondering:
Fitted `LogisticRegression` models in scikit-learn have the attributes `coef_` and `intercept_` to extract the regression coefficients and intercept respectively. The corresponding standard error, confidence interval and p-value are not supplied by scikit-learn. In case you need them you have to resort to statsmodels.